# current time using time.time() doesn't change on refresh [Python]

Tags: python, time, flask

I'm using the `time` module to convert n milliseconds to seconds and add it to the current time.

```
from flask import Flask

currenttime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

@app.route('/api/<seconds>')
def api_seconds(seconds):
    milliseconds = int(seconds) * 1000
    finaltime = int(currenttime + milliseconds)
    return 'Seconds: ' + seconds + '<br />' + 'Milliseconds: ' + str(milliseconds) + \
       '<br />' + 'Time: ' + str(currenttime) + '<br />' + 'Final Time: ' + str(finaltime)
```

This successfully returns the time at the time of running the script but does not change to the current time upon refresh. I have to stop the script and rerun it in order for the time to refresh. How can I make it display the current time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `currenttime` when the `flask` application runs and does not get updated until the application restarts. I would try putting `currenttime` into your route function

```
from flask import Flask
import time

@app.route('/api/<seconds>')
def api_seconds(seconds):
    currenttime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    milliseconds = int(seconds) * 1000
    finaltime = int(currenttime + milliseconds)
    return 'Seconds: ' + seconds + '<br />' + 'Milliseconds: ' + str(milliseconds) + \
       '<br />' + 'Time: ' + str(currenttime) + '<br />' + 'Final Time: ' + str(finaltime)
```

Answer (score 3):

`currenttime` will be evaluated when the script is first loaded, but will not be re-evaluated on concurrent calls to `api_seconds` because your app has already been loaded. You can move the computation of `currenttime` inside of the `api_seconds` method instead and it should execute each time.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks for the answer!